# SQL: Select last 5 instances from a union'd set of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, union

I have 2 separate tables, each with the following columns :

```
ActivityDate | Score | AccountID
```

The initial query is a simple union:

```
SELECT ActivityDate, Score, AccountID FROM Table1 WITH(NOLOCK)
UNION
SELECT ActivityDate, Score, AccountID FROM Table2 WITH(NOLOCK)
```

What I need to do from here is now using this data-set, select the last 5 instances (by `AccountID` & `ActivityDate`). The issue is, ultimately this is going in Tableau and Tableau doesn't play nice with queries if you were trying to do some kind of an into `#Temp` table, so everything has to be done in the query.

Thoughts?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Most recent 5 instances for each account Id or simply most recent 5 total... expecting always 5 records or 5 records per accountID?

Comment: Are you using into #Temp table anywhere, if yes then please put it here so we can see it. thx.

Comment: I'm *assuming* you mean SQL Server **2008** R2 - there's no other version of SQL Server with an `R2` suffix....

Comment: Most recent 5 records per AccountID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ActivityDate, Score, AccountID
from
(
select row_number() over(partition by accountid order by activitydate desc) as rn, 
* from
(
SELECT ActivityDate, Score, AccountID FROM Table1 WITH(NOLOCK)
UNION
SELECT ActivityDate, Score, AccountID FROM Table2 WITH(NOLOCK) 
) t
) t1
where rn <= 5
```

You can use `row_number` function to number the rows and then select the first 5 per accountid.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP(5) 
FROM 
     (SELECT ActivityDate, Score, AccountID FROM Table1 WITH(NOLOCK)
      UNION
      SELECT ActivityDate, Score, AccountID FROM Table2 WITH(NOLOCK)) Test
ORDER BY 
    AccountID, ActivityDate DESC
```